# Google App Engine Search for Go: How to paginate?

Tags: google-app-engine, go

If I query Google App Engine Search for Go, e.g. for the first 10 results, how do I do a follow-up query that fetches the next 10 results? There are no cursors I’m aware of.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**EDIT: Good News!** Since writing this answer, Cursors for the Search API has been completed and published, and so it's generally available.

Check out the [`Cursor`](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/go/search/reference#Cursor) type. A `Cursor` value may be specified in the [`SearchOptions`](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/go/search/reference#Cursor). So when you call [`Index.Search()`](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/go/search/reference#Index.Search), you may pass a `SearchOptions` with a `Cursor` you obtained previously from [`Iterator.Cursor()`](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/go/search/reference#Iterator.Cursor).

Original answer follows below.

---

You are out of luck.

In general Cursors are supported for the Search API (for example see [Java Using cursors](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/search/results#Java_Using_cursors)) and it is also implemented in Go, but the cursor API for searches is incomplete and not exported.

For evidence see the source of [search/search.go](https://github.com/golang/appengine/blob/master/search/search.go): the [`Iterator`](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/go/search/reference#Iterator) type (returned by both [`Index.List()`](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/go/search/reference#Index.List) and [`Index.Search()`](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/go/search/reference#Index.Search) methods) has an unexported `searchCursor` field (currently line #602) which is exactly what we think it is, and it is used internally, it is just not exported.

If you check the source of the [`SearchOptions`](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/go/search/reference#SearchOptions) struct in the same source file (search/search.go) (this is what you can pass to the [`Index.Search()`](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/go/search/reference#Index.Search) method when initiating/performing searches):

```
// Currently starts at line #464:
type SearchOptions struct {
    ...
    // TODO: cursor, offset, maybe others.
}
```

So there is plan to add support for Search cursors, offsets and others, it is just not yet implemented and exported. Hopefully will get added in a future release.

Comment: Cursors and offset seem to now be implemented in the source code on Github...any idea when this might be available on GAE?

Comment: Since this was written it has become available on GAE (in both the classic "appengine" packages and the ones at google.golang.org)